# Google Analytics code not firing

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, umbraco

I have a e-commerce site using Umbraco.
The google analytics code works fine on most of the pages but for some reason doesn't work on the 'secure pages' (pages the user has to log in to see).

I've tried moving the code to various places in the HTML with no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the tracking code you are using? I guess it will be HTTPS right?

Comment: The tracking code I'm using is the standard code from google `<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '#######']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>`

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure the tracking code is actually on the "secure pages"? Have you put it as the very last thing before the closing `<\head>` tag?

Comment: Yes, i've tried putting it all over the place, at the end of the page like the old analytics code, just before the `</head>` tag, even tried loading it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve this is try to track for yourself, if the __utm.gif is called on the page that should be the Goal URL. You can use the Net tab in Firebug, Live HTTP Headers or Fiddler (if you use other browser than Firefox) to track all request on the page.

Check out this 
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-tracking-and-implementation-issues/pjKZ1pou7Sg

FROM GOOGLE

Comment: Tried that, the strange thing is, if I refresh the page then the code fires as it should.